# Get group membership across several domains

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there a simple way to access group memberships of an Active Directory users not only of the local domain, but others as well? The way I figured should work is looping through all domains in the forest and use the Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership. Is there a way to do it using the System.DirectoryServices class? Is it even worth it to bother trying to do it with that class? The script is not intended to be quick and dirty and "just work" but rather be somewhat stable and efficient.

Comment: SO works better if you try and include some code showing what you have tried. It appears like you are asking for the Community to create this for you. A quick google search shows the answer to one of your questions `[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest() | select domains`

Comment: Is this an option? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733025.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would not just do it with the built in Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership cmdlet. It has a parameter "-server" which lets you specify trusted domains.

Comment: This is not correct, -server parameter will not solve the issue here. In another word, if the user belongs to DomainA, but belongs to some groups in DomainB, you cannot user get-adprincipalGroupMembership -identity <user> -Server <DomainB> to list those DomainB groups this <user> belongs to.

Comment: I no longer have any way of testing to verify what you are saying, but it's still valid as a possibility. You could just simply make the script loop through a list of domains while specifying -server for each one to collect a list of all group memberships for a user.

Comment: Actually, I found out the correct parameter is -ResourceContextServer, so roughly, it should be like this get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -id <identity> -Server DomainA -ResourceContextServer DomainB, this will find those DomainB groups which DomainA user belongs to

Comment: DId you find any way to get just groups for one domain independent of another domain? FOr example there is a user A in domain 1 and User B in domain 2 so is there a way to get groups for both of them in single command.